# pdf generator Itext and JAX-RS

Tags: itext, jax-ws

I would like to know how to create class that generates a pdf using `Itext` and send it over to a web browser using `JAX-RS` using the `@GET` and `@Produces` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution, simplified to fit here. I'm using JDK 8 lambdas in the `generate` method, if you can't, just return an anonymous inner class implementing StreamOutput.

```
@Path("pdf")
@Produces(ContractResource.APPLICATION_PDF)
public class PdfResource {

    public static final String APPLICATION_PDF = "application/pdf";

    @GET
    @Path("generate")
    public StreamingOutput generate() {
        return output -> {
            try {
                generate(output);
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                throw new IOException("error generating PDF", e);
            }
        };
    }

    private void generate(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("Test"));
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mock solution that serves PDF file on browser without storing a file on the server side with JAX-RS and IText 5 Legacy.

```
@Path("download/pdf")
public class MockPdfService{

@GET
@Path("/mockFile")
public Response downloadMockFile() {
    try {
        // mock document creation
        com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new Document();
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.getInstance(document, byteArrayOutputStream);
        document.open();
        document.add(new Chunk("Sample text"));
        document.close();

        // mock response
        return Response.ok(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename = mockFile.pdf")
                .build();
    } catch (DocumentException ignored) {
        return Response.serverError().build();
    }
}
```

}